# How to set a dynamic value as a Js.t key in ReScript?

Tags: reason, bucklescript, rescript

Is there a way to set a dynamic value as a `Js.t` key in ReScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not. `Js.t` is a type where all the keys are known at compile time. It's therefore not possible to add or remove keys at runtime. `Js.Dict.t` is a type that's also represented as a JavaScript object and which allows keys to be added or removed at runtime. The trade-off here is that all the values need to have the same type, encoded in the type parameter given to `Js.Dict.t`.